# POSIX semaphores: get PID

Tags: c, semaphore

Is it possible to emulate the System V primitive `semctl(semid,0,GETPID,0)` in an environment using POSIX semaphores?

If it is not possible, I'm looking for a method to know who has done the last operation on a semaphore, I'm going to explain better...

I'm developing a UDP server with preforked children. The father handles SIGCHLD to respawn a dead child. If a child dies in the critical section (namely it has not yet done the sem_post) the father has to recognize this situation and unlock the semaphore.

Comment: according to `man semctl` it's in Linux and in POSIX.1-2001

Comment: @Drakosha `semctl` is used for a different API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want cannot be done. You could emulate the behavior partly by writing your own semaphore based on POSIX robust mutexes (but it would have some disadvantages like not being async-signal-safe), or you could just use a robust mutex instead of a semaphore to begin with.

Comment: I think the "customization path" is too expensive for me. I have found only a way to create a shared mutex between heavy processes: a named semaphore initialized to 1.

Comment: Instead just use named shared memory containing a robust mutex... (`shm_open`) Or even better, put it in a file in the filesystem and `mmap` that. Then you can use fcntl locking for robust initialization of the file the first time it's opened/created.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think it can be done**. I don't see anything like this mentioned in the standard. Your best bet would be to ensure the application has no reason to die in a critical section.

You might think of attaching some state information to each semaphore ("*who did the last DOWN on this semaphore*?"). But then, if multiple processes are allowed to do a down on the semaphore (the semaphore starts with a value greater than 1) you will have to synchronize the way they are updating that information - back to square 1.

Comment: Now I've done a workaround: in the body of the child I have blocked all signals except SIGUSR1 which is the one used by the father to shutdown all children. Obviously, I'm not protected against SIGKILL.